# Trouble creating two rules bordering section of text

Tags: formatting, margins, line

I've used \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} in order to create a solid line from one margin to the other. Then, after a block of text, I use the same command to try and create an identical line. But this latter line begins at an indent and runs off the right side of the page.

I also receive this alert on the latter command, which I can't make sense of: Overfull \hbox (99.26456pt too wide) in paragraph at lines [where I write the second command].

[image]

Thanks for any help. I'm trying to figure out LaTex as I go along.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can try with `\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}`.

Comment: The "alter" basically tells you what you already know - that your rule has extended into the margin. More specifically, it tells you that the line is too long (99.26456pt too long) and therefore, that much of the line has spilled into the margin (and possibly beyond)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I modified my original post to include what I think you're asking for. Let me know if there's anything else I can do.

Comment: @Au101, I considered that too, but the alter is referring to the width, and I'm trying to fix the length of the line. But I also can't figure out why it begins at an indent.

Comment: @Werner, No dice, unfortunately. That actually caused the first line to only exist in the left margin.

Comment: Please include the code as plain text. Copy and paste is much more cumbersome via an image.

Comment: @JoshAvni: We need to see `CV-Preamble.tex`, as it most likely defines `\section` that sets up your display.

Comment: @JoshAvni: I note your example still uses `\textwidth`, while I suggested `\linewidth`.

Comment: @JoshAvni Yeah, what I mean when I say the line is too long is not your solid line that you're trying to draw, but the line on the page, you know, as in this comment is 6 lines long (on my screen), that kind of line. You'd get the same message from a really long word, or a really wide table, or a really big picture. It tells you that the contents of your line are too wide to fit within the margin. In this case, it happens to be that the contents of your line is a ... a line, a horizontal rule, but like I say, you'd get the same warning for a really long word

Answer (score 1):

When used in vertical mode, `\rule` starts a new paragraph and a new paragraph usually adds an indentation (configured by `\parindent`). The indentation is avoided by `\noindent`.

If the line should start at the indentation and the line length shortened by the amount of the indentation, then

```
\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent\relax}{1pt}
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! In the case you suggest, the second line is fixed, but the first line now only exists in the left margin. I was able to fix the problem, albeit a little inelegantly, by inserting an empty `\section{}{}{}` before the first `\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent\relax}{1pt}` followed by the 

    `\section
    {PERSONAL \newline SUMMARY}
    {SUMMARY OF QUALIFICATIONS}
    {PDF:Education}`

Thanks again!